# Android kernel dump

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am busy in the kernel in Android (which is at least close to Linux).

I understand output of `dump_stack()` that I sometimes use to trace things. But when there is a kernel error, the dump also appears but there is an extra line `Exception stack` between the dump.

For curiosity I added a function that accesses `NULL`. When the resulting `NULL` dereference error is raised, this is a part of the dump I get:

```
[<c0055f84>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x138) from [<c0693008>] (panic+0x74/0x194)
[<c0693008>] (panic+0x74/0x194) from [<c0052470>] (die+0x218/0x284)
[<c0052470>] (die+0x218/0x284) from [<c0692df8>] (__do_kernel_fault.part.3+0x60/0x84)
[<c0692df8>] (__do_kernel_fault.part.3+0x60/0x84) from [<c0059d30>] (do_page_fault+0x2cc/0x334)
[<c0059d30>] (do_page_fault+0x2cc/0x334) from [<c0048410>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x9c)
[<c0048410>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x9c) from [<c004e2d0>] (__dabt_svc+0x70/0xa0)
Exception stack(0xe6901ed8 to 0xe6901f20)
1ec0:                                                       00000001 00000003
1ee0: c081ddf8 00000004 410afc4c 00000005 00000004 c09c9218 e63f6800 e6900000
1f00: 00000000 400a5404 c081ddfb e6901f20 c0321ad0 c0321ad4 20000013 ffffffff
[<c004e2d0>] (__dabt_svc+0x70/0xa0) from [<c0321ad4>] (access_null+0x38/0x30c)
[<c0321ad4>] (access_null+0x38/0x30c) from [<c017692c>] (function_that_calls_access_null+0x50/0x94)
```

`access_null()` does the evil access. But the exception stack is not at this function.

What's happening here? What can I do with data in the exception stack section?

Comment: It looks like a stack frame of exception handler. I would suggest just to read the source code.

Comment: I did read but there are hardly any comments and it's hard to understand. My main point of interest is why the stack appears in a function that did not cause the error. For now give up and try to be happy without understanding that to the last detail :-)